# PowerShell IF statement Variables

Tags: powershell

im curious how to use the IF statement logic further in my code. Let me elaborate with an example.

```
$a=1
$b=10000
    if(($a=1) -or ($b=1))
       {write-host ""}  #Here, I want to write what ever variable was $true
                        #in the if statement above.... so I want it to 
                        #write "1" which was $a and was $true in the if
                        #statement...
```

I could write more logic to accomplish this, but im wondering if the values that the if statement used can be used again in the code. Im thinking there is a "hidden" variable maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`($a=1)` is usually an assignment statement. This is not the case in Powershell, but it sure looks like a bug. The Powershell way to do comparison is to use `-eq`. So,

```
if(($a -eq 1) -or ($b -eq1))
```

Now, the simple solution is a bit different. What happens, if both `$a` and `$b` happen to be `1`?

```
$comp = 1 # Value to compare against
$a=1
$b=100
if($a -eq $comp) { write-host "`$a: $a" }
if($b -eq $comp) { write-host "`$b: $b" }
```

This approach is easy to understand, which is in most of the cases more important than other factors like speed.

Comment: actually, i guess i was writing pseudo code sort of. I know how to compare the variables, yes, i should have written ($a -eq 1) -or ($b -eq 1)  What i really want to know, is the if statement will translate that to (true -or false)  b/c a does = 1 and b does not = 1...  So, is that true/false passed in the pipeline?

I want to use the value of the expression ($a -eq 1), which is true, further in the IF logic.

Pseudo Code
a=1; b=1000
if(a=1 or b=1)
   (write-host    'the value that is true above'; without doing more logic, ex: if(a=1)(write-host "blah") etc...

Comment: @NicholasB The `true` is available as `$$`. What are you really after in such a logic? This sounds like a case of [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Its not an XY problem.  I think what you meant to type was $?, that returns "true"  What I want, is to return the value of what is true, or for that matter, false.